# Explanation for this specific case of pipeline stall

Tags: c, optimization, branch, pipeline, microprocessors

I'm a newbie to embedded systems. I'm trying to learn and improve as much as I can. I'm stuck at a point and it's probably OK to just ignore and move on. However, I can't help but let it tickle my mind. I feel like I have to understand this.

On my way, one of the best resources I was able to find is this YouTube playlist by Quantum Leaps, LLC: [Embedded Systems Programming Course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPW8O6W-1chwyTzI3BHwBLbGQoPFxPAPM)

In [Lesson 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZj284kfuE8&index=3&list=PLPW8O6W-1chwyTzI3BHwBLbGQoPFxPAPM) after the time 6.12, Mr. Samek explains some stuff regarding pipeline stalls. At the first glance, I didn't understand a word of it. Then I did some research and readings about pipelines, bubbles, branches etc. to get familiar with concepts and to understand basic mechanisms behind them. I then watched the video again but I still don't understand how the second case is faster.

**Edit to make the question self-contained as much as possible:**

In the video, the code is written as follows:

```
    int main() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < 20) {
            ++counter;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

After the compilation code gets this structure:

```
    ...
    ++counter; // Let's call this line "Line X"
    while (counter < 20) {
        // Assembly instructions to go back to Line X
    }
    ...
```

If I'm not mistaken, Mr. Samek says second code is faster since it avoids a branch. But I don't understand how.

Any help (and advice to learn & improve) is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions here should be self-contained - can you paraphrase enough of the video to make your question answerable?

Comment: it's unclear what exactly your confusion is, but I think you might have misunderstood. The part about pipeline stalls is no longer about the difference in ordering between the code and generated assembly. It's an additional thing to be aware of : every conditional branch can potentially lead to pipeline stalls, so limiting the amount of conditional branches can be advantageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written in C has two branches :

- a conditional branch when testing the `while` loop condition
- an unconditional branch to jump back to the beginning of the loop after the loop body

The generated assembly reorders the code, in order to eliminate the unconditional branch, and only need the conditional branch.

This elimination of a branch instruction results in the speedup that the video author mentions. Refer to the flow images shown in the video to see the difference between the two.

The part about pipeline stalls and branch prediction is unrelated to this point, and instead talks about another thing to be aware of : every conditional branch can potentially lead to pipeline stalls, so limiting the amount of conditional branches can be advantageous.

Comment: So it's safe to think branches as "changing the direction"? In the first case, we **change** the direction with condition being TRUE, then **changing** again after incrementing. In the second case, we start by incrementing and we just follow PC register, then we test the condition. If TRUE, we **change** the direction to incrementation. Then we just follow PC register again. Thus, reducing a branch. Did I get it correct?

Comment: @Motun "changing direction" doesn't sound like a term that fits here. If you're looking for a different word for "branch", you could use "jump". Other than that, you seem to be understanding it.

Comment: I learn better by visualizing these kind of things. Jumping is pretty fine, too. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: branches or jumps go forward and backward, so changing direction is in general not a proper term.  to understand assembly better, you should get the documentation on the machine op codes and look at the number of cycles an instruction requires to operate.  the cheapest instructions to execute time wise will be those that simply advance the program counter (the pointer to the current instruction), so branching requires the processor to load the PC with a different instruction location which is more expensive, thus reducing branches saves time in general